# Java: Why main class does not extend Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

We have one default Thread in our main class but why we in main class do not extend Thread class. Is the reason that the Thread class is somehow included.

Here is what i mean, this is main class:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread.currentThread().getName();

    }

}
```

and we use default Thread, but why in the start we didnt extend Thread class
like this?

```
public class Test extends Thread {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread.currentThread().getName();

    }
}
```

Comment: How would we know why you decided what you decided?

Comment: 1) Maybe it's me, but I find your question very confusing. Just what are you asking? What problem are you trying to solve? 2) For what it's worth, most will recommend that you almost never extend Thread, but rather if the need arises, implement Runnable.

Comment: Probably, to not scare off newbies.

Comment: Well the first part of code is default when we create a project.
My question was, where we see in the code where is Thread class is extended?

Comment: The only valid reason to extend Thread is to change underlying Thread behavior, for example to add logging. If you just want to create a new Thread with your own run behavior, use `new Thread(myRunnable)`. The system has to supply at least a main thread, because you cannot run code to create a thread until you have a thread to run it in.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused a bit. All code runs in some thread, yet the class that defines this code needs not extend Thread. If this were not so, *all* classes had to extend Thread or you couldn't call any of their methods.

Look at the following analogy:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.err.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Now ask yourself why Test does not extend System, and yet it uses fields and methods from System. If you know this, then you can also answer your original question.

Comment: Ah got it, it extends java.lang as default, right ?

Comment: It extends java.lang.Object, but you're still confusing `A extends B` and `A uses B`. One can use things without extending them. Just like in the real world, you can play with a dog (call the Dog method play()) without yourself being a dog.

Comment: So in this case, we use Thread object and methods without extending them?

Answer (score 2):

Whether its life or java , to use a thing you have no need to belong to the same hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I would never, ever have a class extend `Thread`.  There's no new behavior that you'll add.

Better to implement `Runnable` and give that class to a `Thread` or `Executor` to execute it for you.